# Docker cannot connect to daemon set after running docker restart

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a bash script that is running on an ec2 instance.It is running periodically,now the issue is that whenever in the script i run
`sudo service docker start`
it runs but after that when i run `docker ps` it gives me this error
`ERROR: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Now while i have run the command in the script to provide permissions to run docker without sudo but whenever i restart it it seems to rewrite all the configurations.

```
echo "Installing Docker..."
sudo yum install -y docker
#sudo groupadd docker
#sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
tries=3
interval=15s
while [ $tries -gt 0 ]
do
        #sudo yum reinstall -y docker
        #sudo service docker start
        sudo groupadd docker
        sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
        sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
        sudo service docker start
        sudo chkconfig docker on
        docker --version
        sudo service docker restart
        #sudo service docker start
        docker info && break
        let "tries--" && sleep $interval
done
docker info || exit
```

It gives me this error

```
Stopping docker: [60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]

Starting docker:    .[60G[[0;32m  OK  [0;39m]

Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
errors pretty printing info
```

is there any way to run docker without sudo even after running the restart command. Keep in mind that i cannot remove the restart command

Comment: `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` - Do not run this. This effectively gives all users root access to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead
`sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).